# how to rotate log file in spring boot

Tags: spring, logging, yaml

I tried to create a log file configuration that creates a new log file when it sized by 20MB. I'm using the application.yaml file . I've searched for this file configuration in docs and in the internet but didn't work im my machine. I also tried another approaches like the location of the file , the delimiters ( change by / ) , and the hierarchy of the properties in the application.yaml.

so my file configuration its like :

```
server:
  port: 8080
  logging.file: D:\logs\logfile.txt
  logging:
    file:
      max-history: 20
      max-size: 50MB
    level:
      org.springframework.web: DEBUG
      org.hibernate: DEBUG
spring:
  mvc:
    throw-exception-if-no-handler-found: true
  resources:
    add-mappings: false
  security:
    basic:
      enable: false
  server:
    contextPath: /
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://servername.myent.com:5432/appname
    username: meandmsjake
    password: 123abc
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    type: com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource
    hikari:
      maximum-pool-size: 20
      idle-timeout: 10000
  jpa:
    #database-platform: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.postgis.PostgisDialect
    show-sql: true
    properties:
      hibernate:
        temp:
          use_jdbc_metadata_defaults: false
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: none
```

Answer (score 0):

There appear to be two issues here:

1. I'm not sure that setting both logging.file and logging.file.max-history will work in yaml, considering the tree structure. To remedy this, I would try to put these particular properties in the yaml.
2. I don't believe that server.logging.file is the correct property (as you have it here). It should be simply logging.file. Accordingly, the other properties should not be prefixed with "server".

That said, it would be helpful if you posted the version of Spring Boot that you are using.

Comment: The version of Spring boot is 2.1.3.

Comment: In that case the properties are definitely logging.file, logging.file.max-size, logging.file.max-history

*not* server.logging.file, server.logging.file.max-length, server.logging.file.max-history

Comment: I was trying in localhost confs before send to devs server.

Comment: the property names will be as I said regardless of whether you're running locally or on a dev server

Comment: Thanks so much @alexander-katsenelenbogen , but let's explain my pain as you may not understand it : I did tried to loggin my application in a file, I called this logs/logfile.log. It didn't work yet. In my console did the log , like a put a log message like  logger.info("teste 123");